# MFMailComposeViewController init no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i'm trying to create the following extension in Swift:

```
    extension MFMailComposeViewController {

      convenience init(document: Document) {
        self.init()

        // do some configuration...
        setMessageBody("BlaBlaBla", isHTML: false)
      }

    }
```

However I am not able to get this to compile:

> Cannot invoke 'MFMailComposeViewController.init' with no arguments

Which seems strange to me because `MFMailComposeViewController` definitely has an initialiser with no arguments.

Any help on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For sublcassing use `super.init()` instead of `self.init()` and for extensions self

Comment: This is a convince initialiser so using super gives me: "Convenience initializer for 'MFMailComposeViewController' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')". Which is expected...

Comment: import MessageUI

class Document
{
    var name : String?
    
}
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    
    convenience init(document: Document) {
        self.init()
        
        // do some configuration...
        setMessageBody("BlaBlaBla", isHTML: false)
    }
    
}

Answer (score -1):

The reason you got the error is if you run the app on the device or simulator without checking canSendMail method, you will get a `nil` object by initiating it with empty parameter (the default init method).

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {

    convenience init?(document: UIImage) {

        guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else { return nil }

        self.init()
        // continue setup the controller


    }

}
```

You can test this on a simulator without setting up any email accounts by the following code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let controller: MFMailComposeViewController? = MFMailComposeViewController()
        guard let mail = controller else { return }
        present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```